# Convert UTF-8 as string of binary 0 and 1s to code point

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

If you have a string of bits, how do you convert that into the correct code point if that string of `0`s and `1`s is in utf-8 encoding.

For example:

```
accented_a_part1 = "100001"
accented_a_part2 = "00011"

accented_a_int = int(accented_a_part2 + accented_a_part1, 2)
print(accented_a_int),          # => 225
print(unichr(accented_a_int))   # => á    http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf

accented_a_in_utf8 = "110" + accented_a_part2 + "10" + accented_a_part1
accented_a_in_utf8_as_raw_int = int(accented_a_in_utf8, 2)
print(accented_a_in_utf8_as_raw_int),        # => 50081 (not the codepoint you want)
print(unichr(accented_a_in_utf8_as_raw_int)) # => 쎡    (and therefore not the character you want)
```

[UTF-8 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#page-4)

Comment: This seems like a very odd thing to do.  Where are you getting these pieces of utf8?

Comment: I have a raw stream of hex characters, like `16 03 01 00 e3 01`.  This represents a stream of UTF-8 encoded characters (apparently).  I want get those characters.  As I was struggling to make sense of this, I chose to get this into the most basic form, i.e. a string of 1s and 0s

Comment: That is *not the way to go about it*. How are those hex characters presented to you? Literally as hexadecimal characters?

Comment: @AJP: and where did the hex characters come from?  Are they literally a string with hex, like `'16 03 01 00 e3 01'`?

Comment: And that data is *not* UTF-8. The `e3` byte there is not a valid UTF-8 byte in that context.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, literal ASCII characters representing the hex values.

Comment: Why not interpret them as hex values then?

Comment: @MartijnPieters if there's something I can send the ASCII characters representing hex values encoded as UTF-8 and get back a series of integer values, that's fine.

Comment: For anyone actually looking to convert `11000011 10100001` into utf-8:  `hexString = "";
for byte in "11000011 10100001".split(' '):
    hexString += hex(int(byte, 2))[2:];

print(hexString.decode('hex').decode('utf-8'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert literal hex to Unicode:

```
>>> h = '16 03 01 00 e3 01'
>>> h.replace(' ','').decode('hex')
'\x16\x03\x01\x00\xe3\x01'
>>> h.replace(' ','').decode('hex').decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 4: unexpected end of data
>>>
```

If the hex were actual utf8, you'd end up with a Unicode string:

```
>>> h = 'c3 a1'
>>> u = h.replace(' ','').decode('hex').decode('utf8')
>>> u
u'\xe1'
>>> print u
á
```

Comment: `decode('hex').decode('utf8')` thanks that's good.  I appreciate the stream I have is not all valid utf-8 though.  Thanks very much for your input.